# ECM tester 24 volts

Tags: hvac, blower

I purchased the SUPCO "Universal ECM Tester", but I am not sure where attach the two red and black "alligator clips" in order to power the ECM Tester. I've read that it needs 24 volts. My hvac model # is amvc80905cx. Can anyone help me understand where to attach the two alligator clips on my HVAC in order to power the ECM tester?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.